# How to block Outlook rooms scheduling during specific hours?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I created a room in resources under “Rooms and Equipment” to be used by any of our Office 365 users in Outlook.

The name of the room is “Multi-Purpose Rooms.” I would like to block all users from scheduling any meetings in this room during the following hours. 10:00am to 10:30am, 12:00 noon until 1:00pm, and 2:00pm until 2:30pm.

The physical room is brand new. It’s used for meeting, breaks and a lunch area. Is it possible for me to permanently block any from scheduling anything during these periods.

Comment: Just edited your post, but please do not “sign” your posts as if they are a formal letter. That is not the way this site works. Especially the addition of your email address. Questions posted here should be answered here and all adding an email here will ever do is add you to spam lists from bots.

Comment: You can create several recurring/daily meetings that blocks the room for your said time period.